# How to define quadratic weighted kappa as eval_metric in catboost classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, catboost

I am using catboost for a multiclass classification problem. I want to use quadratic weighted kappa as the evaluation metric.

Catboost already has WKappa as an eval_metric but it is linearly weighted variant, not quadratic.

```
clf = CatBoostClassifier(objective='MultiClass',
    eval_metric=q_weighted_kappa(),
    learning_rate=0.01,
    n_estimators=750,
    od_type="Iter",
    depth=35,
    early_stopping_rounds=500,
    random_seed=42,
)
```

I need help to define the function **q_weighted_kappa()** that I can use as specified above.